# Time Limit Exceeds [HS11DIVS] - How to make it faster?

Tags: c, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

Here is the question. From SPOJ [HS11DIVS]. Now , the problem is that my code works perfectly for small numbers. But when it comes to **Large numbers** , the time limit exceeds.

I am not getting any hint on how to make it more efficient. The code is simple enough to understand. I mean its a pretty basic question but difficult to make it efficient.

> For given integers a and b we need to find how many integers in the range [a,b] are divisible by a number x, and have the additional property that the sum of their digits lies in the ,range [l,r] for given l,r.
>
> **Input**
>
> In the first line you're given a and b ( **1 <= a <= b < 10^100** ). In
>   the second line you're given three positive integers x ( 1 <= x <= 10
>   ), l, r ( 1 <= l <= r <= 1,000 ).
>
> **Output**
>
> In the first and only line output the result modulo 1,000,000,007.

And this is my attempt to the question.

**UPDATED :**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sumOfDigits(int number)
{
  int sum=0;
  while(number!=0)
  {
     sum = sum + (number%10);
     number = number/10;
  }
  return sum;
}

/* UPDATED SEGMENT */

unsigned long long int first(unsigned long long int a,unsigned long long int b,int x)
{
  unsigned long long int m = a%x;
      a = a - m + x;
      return a;
} 

int main (void)
{
  unsigned long long int a, b; 
  int x, l, r;
  int counter=0,sum;
  scanf("%llu %llu", &a, &b);
  scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &l, &r);
  a = first(a,b,x);   // gives the first number divisible by x.
  while(a<=b)
  {
    sum = sumOfDigits(a);
    if(l<=sum && r>=sum) // check if sum of digits lies b/w l&r.
    {
        counter+=1;
    }
    a+=x;     // increment a by multiples of x.
  }
  printf("%d", counter);
  return 0;
}
```

Where am i being inefficient? I even calculated the first number divisible by x , and then assign it to a , and then increase a by multiples of x ( a+=x; ).

Here is a sample output :

> **Input**: 
>       1 100 5 10 50
>
> **Output**:   5

Comment: Would you please avoid making changes to the code in the question after the question has been asked? I see in the edit history that you have altered the code repeatedly. This will invalidate any answers already given and is generally not approved of at CR.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to correct first()

```
unsigned long long int first(unsigned long long int a,unsigned long long int b,int x)
{
  // Removed b
  return a;
}       ^^^ otherwise the main loop will run through everything in the main loop (from 0).
```

Though first() looks efficient because you are doing it only once. The questioner may carefully craft a,b,x to take a long time. So you can optimize its evaluation:

```
unsigned long long int m = a%x;
a = a - m + x;  // a now first valid value.
```

Your summing of the digits does a lot of extra work.

```
99   = 18
199  = 19 1 + sum_of_digits(99)
```

You can use this to cache results and re-use them in later calculations.

Pre compute the following array and compile it into your application.

```
sum_cache[10000]   cache  = {
               /* Generated code goes here */

                            };


int sumOfDigits(int number)
{
     int sum=sum_cache[number % 10000];
     for(number = number/10000;number != 0; number/= 10)
     {
         sum    += (number%10);
     }
     return sum;
}
```

#### Edit (based on comments below)

```
int sumOfDigits(int number)
{
  int sum=0;
  while(number!=0)
  {
     sum = sum + (number%10);
     number = number/10;
  }
  return sum;
}
int main()
{
    std::ofstream data("data.d");

    data << 0;
    for(int loop=1; loop < 10000; ++loop)
    {
        data << ", " << sumOfDigits(loop);
    }
}
```

Then change the code above too:

```
sum_cache[]   cache  = {
               /* Generated code goes here */
 #include "data.d"
                       };
```

#### Edit 2:

Improved: (I was hopping you would see the simple optimization)
Does this help?

```
int sumOfDigits(int number)
{
     int sum=0;
     for(;number != 0; number/= 10000)
     {
         sum    += sum_cache[number % 10000];
     }
     return sum;
}
```

#### Max Loop:

```
Original Version (your Code)       100      = 100
First Cache Version                100-4    = 96
Second Cache Version               100/4    = 25
```

Comment: I didnt get the sum_cache part. What is this " Generated code goes here " ? Which code shall i place there?

Comment: You should write a program that generates the pre-computed values for 1->100000 and outputs them as a comma separated list. Then you add the output (the comma separated list of values) into this code.

Comment: But the thing is , i can't create another file and use it. I have to do everything in 1 program only.
here is the link to the problem : **https://hs.spoj.pl/problems/HS11DIVS/**

Comment: 1 program != 1 file.  A single program can be compiled from *n* files.

Comment: @Niteesh Mehra: Once you have generated the numbers and placed the output in a file you can throw the first program away. Using a program is just a short cut to typing out the number by hand (you can type all the numbers by hand and get the same result there is only 10000 in my version but I can see you doing the first 1 million easily).

Comment: Yes am getting the idea. So can u modify and provide me the complete code please?

Comment: The thing is how do i submit it online? Compling n files into one @Ed S.

Comment: @Tux-D : i tried your code. still no help for numbers greater than 10^9. the problem states that b can have value upto 10^100 !

Comment: @Niteesh: Update 2 above. Also don't forget this line: `output the result modulo 1,000,000,007`

Comment: @Tux-D First off , how to even input numbers as large as 10^100 , let alone outputting the result as modulo 1,000,000,007 ??

Comment: Google: "C++ BigInt"